# Redirect to same login route in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to make a Private Route that when the user logs in will refresh and redirect to the same componenent after logging in via /authentication route or else if he is already logged in then go to the component directly

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from "../auth/AuthContext";
import Layout from "../layout/Layout"

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);

  const { isAuthenticated } = authContext;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>(
        <Layout>
        {!isAuthenticated ? (
          <Redirect to={`/authentication?redirect=${props.location.pathname}${props.location.search}`} />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )}
        </Layout>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

/authentication is the route that takes to the login page.

Currently this program work fine until it takes to the route correctly .

For eg: http://localhost:3000/authentication/?redirect=/live

but when the user logs in via this ...it do not redirect to /live and just stays there.

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the main component where you're calling private route?

Comment: <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/live-market" component={LiveMarket}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/a" component={a}/>
            <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
            <Route exact path="/authentication" component={Registeration}/>
@Muneeb

Comment: So, the problem is, when the user logs in on `/authenticated` the page stays there and doesn't redirect to `/live`? 
Or when the login user hits `/live`, the page doesn't redirect to the intended component?

Comment: @Muneeb yeah it doesnt redirect to live